# How to recover the access token of a facebook desktop app?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

When I give in the app id the redirect uri that I get will be a:

`https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?code="some long code"`

Usually like 
`AQDv7kODxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFUMAQqFdB4l9-Bu_AN34woXMmUzJCx8OwRflcxJ4nHmsWx6Z6jnD9IP2DSqnxIJymXB3GCm2FAeWsADV6fHf471KeC11UTSoQRTn4uqu-SsBjiWECL8Vrf0C8N8#_=_`

How do I draw the access token from this code?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the url you can do like this. where actoken is your url

```
 public String getToken() {
        String myu = actoken;

        Pattern startAc = Pattern.compile("="), endAc = Pattern.compile("&");
        Matcher m = startAc.matcher(myu);
        Matcher m1 = endAc.matcher(myu);
        System.out.println(myu);
        while(m.find() && m1.find()) {

            actoken = myu.substring(m.start()+1,m1.end()-1);
        }
        return actoken;
    }
```